# how to sum the value for multiple variables by the same group in r

Tags: r, loops, sum

I need to sum the values for about 40 variables by the same group.

This is an example dataset. So I wanted to sum the values of score1-score5 by region and department.

```
region <- rep(c("south", "east", "west", "north"),times=10)
department <- rep(c("A",  "B","C","D","E"),times=8)
score1 <- rnorm(n = 40, mean = 0, sd = 1)
score2 <-rnorm(n = 40, mean = 3, sd = 1.5)
score3 <-rnorm(n = 40, mean = 2, sd = 1)
score4 <-rnorm(n = 40, mean = 1, sd = 1.5)
score5 <-rnorm(n = 40, mean = 5, sd = 1.5)
df <- data.frame(region, department, score1, score2, score3, score4, score5)
```

This is the code that would lead to the resutls I wanted to have but is there any easier ways to do this:

```
df %>% group_by(region, department) %>%
       summarise(score1=sum(score1), 
                score2=sum(score2),
                score3=sum(score3),
                score4=sum(score4),
                score5=sum(score5))
```

I tried to use a loop but this didn't work:

```
vlist<-c("score1", "score2", "score3", "score4", "score5")
for (var in vlist) {
  df<-df %>% group_by(region, department) %>%
    summarise(var=sum(.[[var]]))
}
```

Is there any other ways or what is wrong with my loop?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `across` - loop `across` the columns that `starts_with` 'score' and get the `sum`

```
library(dplyr)
out1 <- df %>% 
   group_by(region, department) %>% 
   summarise(across(starts_with('score'), sum), .groups = 'drop')
```

---

In the `for` loop, the issue is that `df` is getting updated (`df <-..`) in each iteration and `summarise` returns **only** the columns provided in the group by and the summarised output.  Thus, after the first iteration, 'df' wouldn't have the 'score' columns at all.  If we want to use a `for` loop, get the output in a `list` and then `reduce` with a join

```
library(purrr) 
out_list <- vector('list', length(vlist))
names(out_list) <- vlist
for (var in vlist) {
    out_list[[var]] <- df %>% 
            group_by(region, department) %>%
            summarise(!!var := sum(cur_data()[[var]]), .groups = 'drop')
   }
out2 <- reduce(out_list, full_join, by = c('region', 'department'))
```

-checking the outputs

```
> identical(out1, out2)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: thank you so much. That's super helpful!

Comment: I got one more question. When use across to sum the total by group, how to let r ignore NAs? I tried to use the following code but it's not working.  `summarise(across(starts_with('score'), sum(., na.rm=TRUE)), .groups = 'drop')`

Comment: @llxx2021 you can  either do `summarise(across(starts_with('score'), sum, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')` or `summarise(across(starts_with('score'), ~ sum(., na.rm = TRUE)), .groups = 'drop')`

Comment: got it. Thanks!